# By what process were the Scriptures written down?

Tags: scriptures, inspiration, special-revelation

In a Sunday school class I recently attended, the teacher used a word to describe the process by which Scripture was revealed by the Spirit to the Apostles, then written down. I believe the word he used was 'concoursis'. However, I can't find the word used anywhere.

Is the word 'concoursis' used by any theologian to name that process, or is any other word used specifically as a name for the process?

Note regarding duplicate: I'm not asking if Scripture is inspired, what that means, or how that process works. I'm simply asking if there is a name similar to that word that is used by any writers for the process. This question is no more a duplicate of that question than "What's the name of that blue singing book of Psalms that was a popular children's devotional in the nineties?" is a duplicate of "Does the Bible exhort Christians to teach their children biblical principles?"